# Fabio Load balancing not resolving

Tags: consul, fabio

I have provisioned Fabio job using Nomad as seen below:

```
job "fabio" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "system"

  group "fabio" {
    network {
      port "lb" {
        static = 9999
      }
      port "ui" {
        static = 9998
      }
    }
    task "fabio" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "fabiolb/fabio"
        network_mode = "host"
        ports = ["lb","ui"]
      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 200
        memory = 128
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fabio UI is working on port 9998 on my IP

I have registered a service using consul and it shows up in my fabio UI just fine
[image]

My service is working just fine.. When I go to http://:29504, it shows up my service

When I go to http://:9999/emailhandler-api, it is not resolving at all.

Can someone assist me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in task an arguments to tell fabio witch port they need to listen:

```
args = [
          "-registry.backend=consul", 
          "-proxy.strategy=rnd",
          "-registry.consul.checksRequired=all",          
          "-proxy.addr=127.0.0.1:${NOMAD_PORT_lb};proto=http;",    
          "-registry.consul.register.addr=:${NOMAD_PORT_ui}",
          "-ui.addr=:${NOMAD_PORT_ui}"
]
```